# Display the value of a range-input. "Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML-file. It should display the value of a range-input.

On my JSFiddle page you can find the the [index.html](https://jsfiddle.net/nudelkopf/de6k6wLs/3/). And it works there. But somehow it doesn't work on my web-server. I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null".

```
<html>

<script>
var tilt = document.getElementById("Range");
var tiltt = document.getElementById("tiltRange");

document.addEventListener("input", function() {tiltt.innerHTML = "$" + tilt.value;}, false);

</script>

</body>

60<input id="Range" type="range" min="60" max="170" value="120" />170
<br>

<p id="tiltRange"></p>
```

Comment: when you do your getElementById calls, the rest of the page hasn't been parsed yet, so those IDs don't exist, and the gEBYI call returns a null. Either move the JS code to the **END** of the document, so it's the last thing parsed/executed, or use jquery .ready()

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

Script works before full page loading. This code works in IE9+ and other browsers:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // you will be here after full DOM loading and parsing
  var tilt = document.getElementById("Range");
  ...
});
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)